# How can I add an image to the west toggler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-layout

I'm trying to add an image to the toggler (it's the bar on the left that turns orange when your mouse cursor moves over it). How can I add an image there?

You can see the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XjA4v/

HTML

```
<div class="ui-layout-center" id="inner">
    <div class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
```

Javascript

```
myLayout = $('body').layout({ //    reference only - these options are NOT required because 'true' is the default
    //applyDefaultStyles: true,
    //stateManagement__enabled: true,

    closable: true, // pane can open & close
    resizable: true, // when open, pane can be resized 
    slidable: false, // when closed, pane can 'slide' open over other panes - closes on mouse-out
    livePaneResizing: true,

    north__size: 100,
    north__minSize: 100,
    north__maxSize: 100,
    north__closable: false,
    north__resizable: false,
    north__spacing_open: 0,
    north__spacing_closed: 0,

    west__size: 177,
    west__minSize: 50,
    west__maxSize: 260,
    west__togglerLength_closed: '100%', // toggle-button is full-width of resizer-bar
    west__spacing_closed: 20, // big resizer-bar when open (zero height)
    west__initClosed: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .ui-layout-toggler-hover{
    background:url(''); //your image url
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XjA4v/1/